# Are questions on licensure, exams, and titles within scope?

Tags: discussion

For example (NOT looking for answers):
How is the practice of electrical engineering licensed and regulated in Germany?
In what states is a license required to claim the professional title of "Electrical Engineer"?
What states have reciprocal licensure with Tennessee?

These are not electrical design questions. However, they are questions that affect electrical engineers. The [engineering proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/42542/engineering) was closed at Area 51 recently, so there's nowhere else to ask such questions.

Is this within scope? If not, should it be?

Comment: I would see such questions as on-topic because they come up in the normal course of doing professional electrical engineering.  I can see the point to others voting to close on the ground of being too localized, but I don't think I'd do that as long as the question is well worded, properly formatted, etc, in other words not annoying to read.

Comment: Tangentially on topic: I think the Engineering SX proposal was closed because it was too broad a field. I have proposed the creation of an Electrical (Power) Engineering stack exchange which has a more tightly defined scope. See http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/59748/electrical-power-engineering .

Answer (score 2):

I think those questions are on-topic only insofar as they are discussing electronics design engineering.

Although the site says electrical engineering, it is really about electronics design.  And electronics design engineers do not need to be licensed, at least in my country.  So such questions (for my country) would be off-topic, because they would be about the parts of electrical engineering that need a license, such as designing power wiring for buildings.

Comment: To me it is about electrical engineering, not about career advice, which is how certifications and such work.

Comment: I keep hearing about how the site name is not descriptive of the site's target function.  An engineer would rectify this!

Comment: Unfortunately, "Electronics Design" is trademarked by another publication.  Maybe it is generic enough that it would not stand up in a lawsuit, but we're not going to do the experiment.

Comment: Is it EDM that has it trademarked?  Did SE ever get a cease and desist?